# logical condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery function is like this i want to check when user enter netWeight greater than gross weight at that i want to give alert on it's blur. But it's not working i get both weight on alert but i have with this condition

```
function checkWeight(aboj)
{
  var row     = $(aboj).parents('.itemRow');
  var gWeight = row.find('.gWeight').val() != '' ? row.find('.gWeight').val() : 0;
  var netWeight = row.find('.netWeight').val() != '' ? row.find('.netWeight').val() : 0;


  if(gWeight > netWeight)
  {
    alert("Please Check Gross Weight");
  }
}
```

my html is like this

```
<input type="text" class="input netWeight" name="netWeight[]"  onblur=" checkWeight(this);>
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: Please provide relevant html and show where you call this function

Comment: me update my html code @charlietfl

Comment: @gnerkus don't remove relevant html from question just to change some text

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you. That wasn't intentional. I only improved an earlier edit. I didn't notice the HTML had been removed. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing strings. You need to parse the string value to float or integer to make the numeric comparison:

- [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
$('body').on('click', '#compare', function () {
  var gross = parseFloat($('#gross').val());
  var net = parseFloat($('#net').val());
  
  if (gross>net) {
    alert('gross: ' + gross + ' is greater than net: ' + net);
  }
  if(net>gross) {
    alert('net: ' + net + ' is greater than gross: ' + gross);
  }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Gross:<input type="text" id="gross"/>
<br/>
Net:<input type="text" id="net"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="compare" value="Compare"/>
```

Comment: why? are you sure? which other issue could it be? I expect that at least the entered data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

me get salutation with using parseFloat

```
function checkWeight(aboj)
{
  var row     = $(aboj).parents('.itemRow');
  var gWeight = row.find('.gWeight').val() != '' ? row.find('.gWeight').val() : 0;
  var netWeight = row.find('.netWeight').val() != '' ? row.find('.netWeight').val() : 0;


  if(parseFloat(gWeight) < parseFloat(netWeight))
  {
    alert("Please Check Gross Weight");
  }
}
```